# Is OSX essential to run xCodeBuild, or could it run on a unix/linux box

Tags: ios, xcode

I've not been able to find a definitive answer to this so far, does XCodeBuild have to run on OS X in order to build iOS apps, or could it run on unix/linux?

The intention is to get it set up with Jenkins for continuous integration.

Comment: It's only available for OSX and won't run under any other O/S.

Comment: Non of the Apple dev tools are supported on any operating system other than OSX, that includes xcodebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At work we run all continuous integration on Mac servers despite being a Linux-only office. There is no availability of the Xcode tools on Linux. Even then the best support for those tools is only of the latest version of Mac OS.